# Create page structure one time for all languages

Tags: django-cms, multilingual

I'm testing the Django CMS and I'm looking for a way to create the pages one time for all languages. Currently I have to create a new page for each languages and the content/plugin/structure is not shared between the different languages.

Is there a way to achieve this?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2):

The built-in management command [`./manage.py cms copy lang`](http://docs.django-cms.org/en/release-3.4.x/reference/cli.html#cms-copy-lang) copies the entire page tree from one language to another. The page tree stays unchanged and the plugin trees are transferred. That is fine if you want to bootstrap a new language for the **entire** site.

If you want to copy the plugin trees for **only one page**, you can use the language menu from the toolbar: `Language -> Copy all plugins` if you are viewing the *target language*. This is fine, if you only have one page.

If you want to bootstrap a language for a **page tree**, i.e. a page and all its children, then you either have a lot of clicking to do, or use this short management command I created based on the original DjangoCMS `./manage.py cms copy long` command. It allows to specify a page to copy either by its id or by its name in the source language (attention: it has to be unique).

Copy [this snippet](https://gist.github.com/fsbraun/677da985a6c023f475b6777579054027) into any of your application's command folder: `my_app/management/commands/`. Once you've copied the file you'll have a new Django management command available: `./manage.py copylang`. Usage examples:

```
./manage.py copylang --from-lang=en --to-lang=nl --tree="Home" 
./manage.py copylang --from-lang=en --to-lang=nl --tree_id=36 --force
```

The page id needed for the `--tree_id` option can be easily inferred from the page admin by hovering over the page's preview icon. The page id is part of the link: .../page/*page_id*/*lang*/preview/...

If you leave out the `--tree`and the `--tree_id` options the command will revert to DjangoCMS's original `cms copy lang` behaviour.

Answer (score 2):

The management command provided by @Fabian is quite useful.
I updated the command code [here](https://gist.github.com/beeduino/4d8c42e6c2005689cc16a74e986299ba) to reflect the changes in django-cms API:

```
        # pages = [head] + list(head.children.drafts())             
        pages = [head] + list(head.get_child_pages().drafts())
```

Tested against django-cms 3.5.3 and 3.7.4.
All credits go to @Fabian.